# nimble に含まれる一部のコマンドが使えない

Tags: windows, nimble

コマンドプロンプトで `nimble list` を実行すると、以下のエラーが表示されました。

```
oserr.nim(95)            raiseOSError
Error: unhandled exception: アクセスが拒否されました。
Additional info: C:\Users\�v�ہ@���R�� [OSError]
```

一方でコマンドプロンプトで `nimble` と単体で入力する分にはnimbleの中に含まれる色々なコマンドが表示され、ちゃんと動作しているようでした。
どうすればnimbleコマンドを十分に使えるようになるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

英数字以外 (たとえば平仮名や漢字) や空白がパスに含まれる場合の配慮が出来ていないソフトはよくあります。

nimble はデフォルトでは各種の設定や関連パッケージなどを `C:\Users\<ユーザー名>\.nimble` 以下に保存するようです。 ユーザー名に英数字以外を使っているような場合に処理できていないのだと思われます。

これらのデータにアクセスしない場合は問題なく実行できるのでしょう。

このディレクトリの指定は `nimble` コマンドの `--nimbleDir` オプションか環境変数 `NIMBLE_DIR` で出来るようですのでパスが英数字で構成されるディレクトリを指定してください。